# Idenify non-existing html elements

Tags: jquery, html

If i fetched all elements of HTML doc and store them in an array.
Now suppose i delete some element using jquery remove() method. I know it would delete its sub-child too. Now i want to traverse the list and want to know which child elements are deleted too.
Look at this code :-

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        var list = $('*');
        for (var i=0; i<list.length; i++) {
            console.log(i + " " + list[i].tagName);
        }
        $("table").remove();
        for (var i=0; i<list.length; i++) {
            if ($(list[i]).parent().length == 0) console.log(list[i].tagName + "does not exist in dom now");
            else console.log(i + " " + list[i].tagName + " " + $(list[i]).parent().get(0).tagName);
        }
    });
```

HTML part is :-

```
<div>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td> Hi this is Sachin </td>
            <td> Hi this is Rahul </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

And the output I am receiving is :_

```
0 HTML parent.html:9
1 HEAD parent.html:9
2 SCRIPT parent.html:9
3 SCRIPT parent.html:9
4 BODY parent.html:9
5 DIV parent.html:9
6 TABLE parent.html:9
7 TBODY parent.html:9
8 TR parent.html:9
9 TD parent.html:9
10 TD parent.html:9
0 HTML undefined parent.html:14
1 HEAD HTML parent.html:14
2 SCRIPT HEAD parent.html:14
3 SCRIPT HEAD parent.html:14
4 BODY HTML parent.html:14
5 DIV BODY parent.html:14
TABLEdoes not exist in dom now parent.html:13
7 TBODY TABLE parent.html:14
8 TR TBODY parent.html:14
9 TD TR parent.html:14
10 TD TR
```

I don't understand why td and tr are showing their parents. They would be considered as deleted too. Is there any other way to find out which are the deleted items in my list now.
Thanks in advance

Comment: what is your goal? if you dont want to have all the removed element's childrens from the `list`, why dont just re-populate list with same selector and reset the for loop.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is your check to see if an element has a parent or not:

```
if ($(list[i]).parent().length == 0)
```

Just because you have removed an element from the DOM doesn't mean its descendants have been removed from that element. They *have* been removed from the DOM (since their parent has), but they all still have that parent.

You could use [`closest`](http://api.jquery.com/closest/) to check if the element has a `body` ancestor instead:

```
if ($(list[i]).closest("body").length == 0)
```

Since the elements are no longer in the DOM, they shouldn't have a `body` ancestor.

---

As a side note, since `0` evaluates to `false`, you can simplify your condition a little:

```
if (!$(list[i]).closest("body").length)
```

Comment: I got some doubt since I have removed element from dom So when i am accessing element like $(list[i]) should not it select the element only in document it should be null according to me but actually is is not.Why is this so even after removing some element from document i can access it using $(list[i])..

Comment: @blunderboy - The jQuery (`$`) function does not only select elements in the DOM. You can pass an existing element to it (or even a string of HTML) to create a jQuery object wrapping that element. For example, you could create a jQuery object containing `list[i]`, and then append it to an element in the DOM: `$(list[i]).appendTo("#elem");`. Does that make sense?

Comment: Perfect james as I have read on net too...Fully agree and enjoying JS :)